# Cannot align button beside search bar

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align my search bar beside my dropdown button. I have tried aligning them but it doesn't work. Both buttons are located in a container as well, hence the search bar is 100% of the container's width. I have also tried align-left, align-right and alight-centre. I also changed the display of the button to "flex".

My current buttons look as such:-

[image: currentui]

```css
.has-search .form-control {
    padding-left: 38px;
}

.has-search .form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>sample</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/restaurants.js"></script>
    </head>
<body onload="getRestaurantData()">
        <!-- This is where top navigation html codes is -->
        <div w3-include-html="top-navigation.html"></div>
        <!-- This is the container that holds the initial message, heading, and movies -->



        <div class="container">
        <!-- The message will be shown when the page loads and will
        disappear after the movies are loaded -->



            <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select cuisine
                    <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this blog">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>


            <!-- Displays thumbnails of the movies here -->
            <div id="restaurantsTable" class="row"></div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <!-- Include footer here -->
        <div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>
    </body>
<script src="js/w3.js"></script>
<script>
        //to bring in other HTML on the fly into this page
        w3.includeHTML();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: both are in the same container, but are not in the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change HTML CODE like

```
<div class="container">
        <!-- The message will be shown when the page loads and will
        disappear after the movies are loaded -->

<div class="d-flex"> /*Changes Here*/
    <div class="dropdown col"> /*Changes Here*/
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select cuisine
                    <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group col-12 flex-fill"> /*Changes Here*/
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this blog">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Displays thumbnails of the movies here -->
            <div id="restaurantsTable" class="row"></div>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/eajpcuh3/2/

Answer (score 1):

if you are already using bootstrap, I'd suggest to use it's possibilities.

**The main idea** is that element with `flex` property, should surround the items you want to work with.

In your case add class `d-flex` to your`<div class="container">`. But better make separate div with that class, that surrounds `dropdown` and `input-group`. It will give more opportunities to manipulate. Then to add some space after `dropdown` you can add to that div, for example, class `mr-2` which adds margin from right.

The result is something like this.

```css
.has-search .form-control {
    padding-left: 38px;
}

.has-search .form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>sample</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/restaurants.js"></script>
    </head>
<body onload="getRestaurantData()">
        <!-- This is where top navigation html codes is -->
        <div w3-include-html="top-navigation.html"></div>
        <!-- This is the container that holds the initial message, heading, and movies -->



        <div class="container">
        <!-- The message will be shown when the page loads and will
        disappear after the movies are loaded -->



            <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="dropdown mr-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select cuisine
                        <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this blog">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
                      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>


            <!-- Displays thumbnails of the movies here -->
            <div id="restaurantsTable" class="row"></div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <!-- Include footer here -->
        <div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>
    </body>
<script src="js/w3.js"></script>
<script>
        //to bring in other HTML on the fly into this page
        w3.includeHTML();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.container {
  display: flex
}
```

This will align dropdown and search bar side by side then you can give spacing according to your requirement.

Comment: Imho not the best idea to change framework class properties. And also you have to do more adjustments to get better view. For example, after your suggested way, we have to deal with stretched search button.